# web-bluetooth Get service long wait

Tags: web-bluetooth

I am a novice

I get the UUID of the service through NRF connect, but I have been waiting for it

```
this.device=null;
this.server=null;
function connect() {
    return navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({filters:[{services:[ '0000ffb0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb' ]}]})
        .then(device => {
            this.device = device;
            return device.gatt.connect();
        })
        .then(server => {
            this.server = server;
            return Promise.all([
                //Keep waiting
                server.getPrimaryService('0000ffb0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb').then(service => {
                    this.service = service;
                    console.log(service);
                     return Promise.all([
                        //this._cacheCharacteristic(service,''),
                     ])
                })
            ]);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested for an hour
'''
server.getPrimaryService (0x1800);
'''
Only once
The rest of the time is waiting